# Re-link Google Home Account with Assistant Pi on Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-home, google-assistant

I installed the Google Assistant on a Raspberry Pi 3+ and it works perfectly.

I see the Raspberry in my Google Home App and I can configure some features. However, by mistake, I have unlinked from the Google Home App on my mobile the device of my Google account.

Now I can see it but I can not access certain features of the assistant on the Raspberry, such as selecting the default output speaker or access to the options of "personalized answers" among others.

That screen has disappeared in the Google Home App in the assistant on the Raspberry. How can I rescue it? How can I re-pair the device with my Google account to fix it, since I believe that's the problem?